# Shared memory and conditional variables between 32-bit and 64-bit Linux processes

Tags: linux, shared-memory

I have two Linux C/C++ programs that communicate using shared memory (shm_open, mmap, etc.) with mutex (pthread_mutex_*) and conditional variables (pthread_cond_*) in that shared memory. If both programs are compiled (using gcc) and run in 32-bit Linux (RHEL) machines, they communicate successfully. If, on the other hand, one process is compiled in 64-bit machine, the other is still compiled in 32-bit machine (due to legacy code), and both are run in a 64-bit machine, pthread_cond_wait in the 32-bit process waits forever even after the 64-bit process does pthread_cond_signal. What am I missing here. Or is it impossible to use conditional variables and mutex between a 32-bit and a 64-bit application?

Comment: It probably is impossible. You have to check the layout of e.g. `pthread_mutex_t` to be sure.

Comment: Here's what I decided to do: use pipes to implement condition variables. See http://ace.ucv.ro/sintes12/SINTES12_2005/SOFTWARE%20ENGINEERING/44.pdf